# Bessel's inequality in Fourier series

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

[image: bessel inequality]

In Bessel's inquality, how does the series of sum of the squares of Fourier coefficients converges ? Is there any particular result for the convergence of series that they have used ?

Comment: Why did you tag this with real-algebraic-geometry?

Comment: I didn't tag it with real-algebraic-geometry

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums of a serise of non-negative numbers is an increasing sequence. If it is bounded then it is convergent. In this case the bound is $\frac 1 {\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{2}(t)dt$.